# MomentJS from 00:00 to 23:59

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I've been trying to add this slider:
http://ionden.com/a/plugins/ion.rangeSlider/demo_advanced.html

This is my sample code:

```
$("#range").ionRangeSlider({
    min: +moment().subtract(12, "hours").format("X"), //need to change to 00:00
    max: +moment().format("X"), //need to change this to 23:59
    from: +moment().subtract(6, "hours").format("X"), 
    grid: true,
    force_edges: true,
    prettify: function (num) {
        var m = moment(num, "X").locale("en");
        return m.format("HH:mm");
    }
});
```

**I would like to add min to 00:00 and max to 23:59**

I tried doing

```
moment("1234", "hmm").format("HH:mm")
```

I'm getting either invalid date or NaN.

Please help me. I'm not sure where I'm going wrong.

Comment: The reason why you get **invalid date or NaN**, because `min` and `max` expects number while `moment("1234", "hmm").format("HH:mm")` returns `string`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A moment object is a datetime, you cannot just add a time only. Instead create the object and change the time:

```
min: +moment().startOf("day").format("X"),
max: +moment().endOf("day").format("X"),
```

Then the `prettify` callback will only show the time in the slider.

Comment: Thank you @str this worked. But let's say if i want to put my slider at a particular time. What should I do'? Let's say my min is at 13:00 hours. How can I come.

Comment: @TechnoCorner As I said "create the object and change the time". `from: +moment().hours(13).minutes(0).format("X")`. Moment.js has a good documentation that you can look into.